# jQuery sortable issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i have list of items and jQuery Sortable plugin.

After click to activation sort button, i do:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable();
$( ".sortable" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", false );
```

After click to save new order button i do:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", true );
// Some Ajax to save actual positions
```

After click to reset ordering i do:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable("cancel");
$( ".sortable" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

And heres the issue:

Step 1: I activate sorting, do some sorting and save it. Everything is OK.

Step2: Now, i again click to button to activate sorting and again sort. Now i change my mind, click to reset sorting button. But sorting positions are revert long ago before step 1 :(

I need to save position of sorted items after saving them in step 1, so after click to reset button in step 2 theese items have to go to status after step 1.

Thank you very much!

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you create a http://www.jsfiddle.net for your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use local storage or session storage - depends on what do you want.
Do you have many or only one object annotated with .sortable class?
If you have only one, there is a simple solution - just store all children.

```
localStorage.setItem('storedChildren', JSON.stringify($(".sortable").children());
```

then retrieve them, clear $(".sortable") and put your items there.
Your reset will consist in putting previously stored objects.

P.S. You should probably upgrade this code, I haven't much experience with Jquery.

Comment: Thanks, similar solution i have in my mind too, but it seems for me too  ugly, i hope, that jquery itself can resolve my problem.